# db: find table name by id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, indexing

It's possible to find a table name by an id?
I have multiple tables that extends another table, when I find the id in the "super" table, I'd like to know in which subtable is that id.
There is a way with indexing to do that or another way?
Thanks

Comment: Unless you're creating those tables dynamically, i do not see the point in selecting any kind of index just to identify a table, you can just as easily identify table by it's name.
Otherwise if i did not understood your question correctly you might be looking something like that:
SELECT relid, relname FROM pg_stat_all_tables where schemaname = 'YourSchema';

Comment: to explain I can write an example: I have a table called article and two tables called news and courses. article contains the common info for news and courses and the id. article id 1 refer to news or courses with id 1. to avoid to make a select on both table to find the id 1, I'd like to know the tablename to make directly the query on that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is really unclear but ...

article(stuff,id)
news(id references article(id),morestuff)
courses(id references article(id),evenmorestuff)

So you're using the id from article to link to either news or courses and would like to avoid select union from news AND courses ?

1) your current query does not contain this information

2) A few ways to do this:

a) you change your datamodel to something more generic (article,r_article_news,news,r_article_courses,courses) and determine that on this basis

b) you add the information in the article table (add a column named type, where you will enter either news or courses)

c) you make your first query slightly heavier to determine that automatically

```
SELECT a.*,b.type 
FROM article a 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT id,'news' AS type 
    FROM news 
    UNION 
    SELECT id,'courses' AS type 
    FROM courses) b 
ON a.id=b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tags say `mysql` and `postgresql`. Since it is not clear which one you want, here is the solution for `mysql`.

Obviosly, you can do this only if your tables have a FOREIGN KEYS set. For example, if you have a database `dogs_and_peaople` with two tables:

```
dogs
------
id
owner_id -- foreign key on people.id
name

people
------
id
name
surname
```

If you want to find out, which table and field are reperenced by `dogs.owner_id`, you can look in `information_schema` database, like this:

```
SELECT 
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'dogs_and_peaople' -- database name
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'dogs'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'owner_id'
```